# Apk testing. Get access to resources

Tags: android, flutter, resources, apk

I would like to test a Flutter app. The apk is already uploaded to be tested, but to go through the login I have to give them the name of the resource where they should write the username. The same with the password and the login button.
How/Where can I get those references or resources name?

screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: I guess it is not possible for now. See: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16921

Comment: Then how It´s supposed to realize the tests?